# Можно ли во Flutter передать название для иконки строкой

Tags: flutter

У меня есть 5 кнопок, отчаются они между собой только иконками и чтобы не писать виджет для каждой можно ли сделать какой-то класс шаблон, который будет принимать названия иконок и возвращать кнопку с этими иконками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы похоже самую главную часть о Flutter пропустили. Вы можете делать свои виджеты, какие только хотите:

```
// делаем свой виджет класс
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // конструктор этого класса, принимающий поле icon
  MyWidget(this.icon);
  
  // поле icon для нашей иконки
  final IconData icon;
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(icon),
          Text('text'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
MyWidget(Icons.ac_unit),
MyWidget(Icons.audiotrack),
```